# Why that's wrong?

Tags: java

I did a program. And I used an Array method. I just found it by trying. But it is working. My code line is this:

```
ProductArray productArray = new ProductArray(50);
```

I tried to create an Array. My code fails when I try the normal definition. Like this:

```
ProductArray[] productArray = new ProductArrat[50];
```

What's the reason of this? What is wrong and what is correct? I could not find a definition like the one in the first code I showed you. My full code is here but "insert,search,display,delete" methods are in different class.

```
public class TestProductArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ProductArray productArray = new ProductArray(50);

    Product p0 = new Product("Product0","Description0",199);
    Product p1 = new Product("Product1","Description1",799);
    Product p2 = new Product("Product2","Description2",599);
    Product p3 = new Product("Product3","Description3",499);
    Product p4 = new Product("Product4","Description4",599);
    Product p5 = new Product("Product5","Description5",299);
    Product p6 = new Product("Product6","Description6",99);
    Product p7 = new Product("Product7","Description7",4499);
    Product p8 = new Product("Product8","Description8",3999);
    Product p9 = new Product("Product9","Description9",2999);

    productArray.insert(p0);
    productArray.insert(p1);
    productArray.insert(p2);
    productArray.insert(p3);
    productArray.insert(p4);
    productArray.insert(p5);
    productArray.insert(p6);
    productArray.insert(p7);
    productArray.insert(p8);
    productArray.insert(p9);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Searching Product0");
    if (productArray.search("Product0") != null) {
        productArray.search("Product0").displayProduct();
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Searching Product7");
    if (productArray.search("Product7") != null) {
        productArray.search("Product7").displayProduct();
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Searching Product99");
    if (productArray.search("Product99") != null) {
        productArray.search("Product99").displayProduct();
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Deleting Product2");
    productArray.delete(p2);
    System.out.println("Deleting Product3");
    productArray.delete(p3);
    System.out.println("Deleting Product15");
    productArray.delete(new Product("Product15","Description15",300));

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Display whole array");
    productArray.display();
   
    
}
```

}

Comment: Is `ProductArrat` a copy and paste error?

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Comment: I’d probably just google for "how do I define a Java array" or something. Unrelated, but when asking about specific errors it’s best to include the specific error.

Comment: I wrote it with my hand. I am sorry. It should be ProductArray.

Comment: Yes. I am so sorry. I am new here. I forgot to show error... When I did "ProductArray[] productArray = new ProductArray[50];" my methods are not working. Like "insert,delete,search,display". Error message: "error: cannot find symbol
        productArray.insert(p0);
  symbol:   method insert(Product)
  location: variable productArray of type ProductArray[]"

Comment: Why do you expect the methods defined for the instances of `ProductArray` should work for the *array of `ProductArray`*?

Comment: Ok.  I think I had difficulty explaining the question I was asking. What is the difference between these 2 codes? 
ProductArray productArray = new ProductArray(50);
and
ProductArray[] productArray = new ProductArray[50];

Answer (score 1):

When array of `ProductArray` is created as mentioned in the question, it is filled with nulls initially and it needs to be populated first with instances of `ProductArray`.

Then, the `ProductArray` methods `insert, search, delete, display` are not applied to array of `ProductArray` as with any `Object` and `Object[]` in Java.  The element of array has to be retrieved by the index first.

That is,

```java
ProductArray[] arr = new ProductArray[50];
arr[0] = new ProductArray(50);

Product p0 = new Product("Product0","Description0",199);
Product p1 = new Product("Product1","Description1",799);
// ...
arr[0].insert(p0);
arr[0].insert(p1);
// ... etc.
System.out.println("Searching Product0");
if (arr[0].search("Product0") != null) {
    arr[0].search("Product0").displayProduct();
}
System.out.println();
```

If `insert, search, etc.` is called on `arr[1]` *before* assigning a new `ProductArray` to this cell of the array, a `NullPointerException` will be thrown.